# Insert row where sequential value is missing, Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office, sequential

I am using the following VBA code to insert a blank row where a sequential value is missing in excel.

```
Sub test() 
Dim i As Long, x, r As Range 
For i = Range("b" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1 
    x = Mid$(Cells(i, "b"), 2) - Mid$(Cells(i - 1, "b"), 2) 
    If x > 1 Then 
        Rows(i).Resize(x - 1).Insert 
        Cells(i - 1, "b").AutoFill Cells(i - 1, "b").Resize(x), 2 
    End If 
Next
```

This works fine unless the last value is missing.
For example I am filling in the blanks for groups of 5.
Where middle numbers are missing:
1
2
4
5
The code will insert a blank row for the missing value to become:
1
2

4
5
However if the last value, 5, was missing, a row will not be inserted.
So:
1
2
4
Becomes:
1
2

4
Is there a way to set a maximum to ensure the final value will be recognised as missing?

Comment: There's missing a rule to derive the expected number of values from. For instance from your last example that rule could be "the number in cell must equal its Index in the column", but given the presence of Autofill method I guess that rule is more complex. Anyhow, once given the "rule" &there comes out the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer was given to me on another forum:

http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=200184&goto=newpost**

```
Sub Reply() 
i = 1 
Do While Cells(i, 2) <> "" 
    j = Cells(i + 1, 2).Value - Cells(i, 2).Value - 1 
    If j < 0 Then j = 8 - Cells(i, 2).Value + Cells(i + 1, 2).Value 
    For k = 1 To j 
        Rows(i + k).EntireRow.Insert 
    Next k 
    i = i + k 
Loop 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
Sub test()
Dim i As Long, x, r As Range, lMax As Long, lRw As Long

lRw = Range("b" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
lMax = InputBox("Enter Maximum Value", "Maximum Input Req.", Application.Max(Range("B2:B" & lRw)))

For i = lRw To 2 Step -1
    If i = lRw Then
        x = lMax - Mid$(Cells(i - 1, "b"), 2)

        If x > 1 Then
            Cells(i - 1, "b").AutoFill Cells(i - 1, "b").Resize(x + 1), 2
        End If
    Else
        x = Mid$(Cells(i, "b"), 2) - Mid$(Cells(i - 1, "b"), 2)

        If x > 1 Then
            Rows(i).Resize(x - 1).Insert
            Cells(i - 1, "b").AutoFill Cells(i - 1, "b").Resize(x), 2
        End If
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

**Revised Code**

```
Sub test()
Dim i As Long, x, r As Range, lMax As Long, lRw As Long

lRw = Range("b" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
lMax = InputBox("Enter Maximum Value", "Maximum Input Req.", Application.Max(Range("B2:B" & lRw)))

For i = lRw To 2 Step -1
    If i = lRw Then
        x = lMax - Cells(i - 1, "b").Value

        If x > 1 Then
            Cells(i - 1, "b").AutoFill Cells(i - 1, "b").Resize(x + 1), 2
        End If
    Else
        x = Cells(i, "b").Value - Cells(i - 1, "b").Value

        If x > 1 Then
            Rows(i).Resize(x - 1).Insert
            Cells(i - 1, "b").AutoFill Cells(i - 1, "b").Resize(x), 2
        End If
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I tried your code but get a mismatch error 13, with bug at line

x = Mid$(Cells(i, "b"), 2) - Mid$(Cells(i - 1, "b"), 2)

I thought this may be due to zeros in column 'b' but when I removed them the same thing happened.

Comment: Hey, thanks again for helping!! Ran the new code. Still does not add a blank row if the end value is missing. Tried adding a maximum value of one more than the actual, but that didn't help.